# iOS Project could not build in Github actions : Error code 65

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have this issue while i tried to build my xcode project in github actions:

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medipills-fcfyzvumkxvttzcpwnfwxeldqivu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medipills.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Medipills.build/Script-53C11E9C2A3B69C60070480A.sh (in target 'Medipills' from project 'Medipills')
(1 failure)
Error: Process completed with exit code 65.
```

Here's my workflow file :

```
# Test 
name: App Control

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_test:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    env:
      xcode_version: 14.3

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up GoogleService-Info.plist
        run: echo "$GOOGLE_SERVICE_INFO" > Medipills/GoogleService-Info.plist
        
      - name: Check Comfortaa.ttf permissions
        run: ls -l Medipills/Comfortaa.ttf
        
      - name: Create Comfortaa directory
        run: mkdir -p $HOME/work/Downloads/Comfortaa

      - name: Copy Comfortaa.ttf
        run: cp Medipills/Comfortaa.ttf $HOME/work/Downloads/Comfortaa/Comfortaa.ttf
 
      - name: Create Downloads directory
        run: mkdir -p $HOME/work/Downloads

      - name: Copy JSON files
        run: |
         cp Medipills/Animations/syrup.json $HOME/work/Downloads/syrup.json
         cp Medipills/Animations/medicine.json $HOME/work/Downloads/medicine.json
         cp Medipills/Animations/blue_pill.json $HOME/work/Downloads/blue_pill.json

      - name: Copy GoogleService-Info.plist
        run: cp Medipills/GoogleService-Info.plist $HOME/work/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist

      - name: Clean project
        run: xcodebuild clean -scheme Medipills -project Medipills.xcodeproj

      - name: Build Medipills
        run: xcodebuild build -scheme Medipills -project Medipills.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max"

      - name: Run Unit Tests
        run: xcodebuild test -scheme Medipills -project Medipills.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max"

      - name: Fix Script Permissions
        run: chmod +x /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medipills-fcfyzvumkxvttzcpwnfwxeldqivu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medipills.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Medipills.build/Script-53C11E9C2A3B69C60070480A.sh

      - name: Run Script
        run: sh /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medipills-fcfyzvumkxvttzcpwnfwxeldqivu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medipills.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Medipills.build/Script-53C11E9C2A3B69C60070480A.sh
```

Do you know how to solve this issue ? I've tried everything but the problem is still there with the same exit code

I tried to delete my derived data, copied my files directly to the project source, check if all my project files are present in my github.

Comment: You have any Pods in your project?

Comment: No, i use Swift package manager

Comment: @Richard could you also share the contents of the script? What's that used for?

Comment: @EDUsta :

"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

Input files: 

"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run"

Its in my build phases in order to use crashlytics

Comment: @Richard did you find any solution? I am having the same issue with crashlytics

Comment: @BlackM Yes it was the path of the file which was in the wrong place.